# Constructing a table for each variable to show time periods in which NA's occur

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to create a table in **R** for each variable in my data set macro to give me the year(s) (we have a date variable timestamp) in which our NA's in the variables occur.

I tried this:

```
for (var in names(macro)) {
  var <- paste("macro$",var, sep="")
  print(var)
  print(table(year(macro$timestamp[is.na(var)])))
}
```

but it does not work.

When I don't write it within the for loop it, however, works, e.g.:
`table(year(macro$timestamp[is.na(macro$gdp)]))`

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `var` as a character string, so it is not `NA`.  Try the following...

```
for (var in names(macro)) { 
    print(var) 
    print(table(year(macro$timestamp[is.na(macro[,var])])))
}
```